# magento: -e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully

Tags: patch, magento-1.9.1

I got this error when I tried to install the path PATCH_SUPEE-1533.
I have magento 1.9.1.0

```
sh PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh 
PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh: 24: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh: 24: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh: 29: 0: not found
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
-e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The security patch SUPEE-1533 is already there in magento 1.9.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Check the two files the patch applies to:
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php

Search for serialize in both of those.  If you find serialize or unserialize, you need to manually apply the fix.

Refer to lines 171, 172 in the patch file for Graph.php and 184,185,186 for DashboardController.php